# rxjs modular imports and bundle size (webpack2/angular2 cli)

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-cli, webpack-2

If I have a component -- Component A -- with imports such as:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
```

and I have another component -- Component B -- with duplicate imports:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
```

And I build using a `ng build --prod` will the `CLI` de-duplicate the imports or will I have 2x copies of each import in my bundle? Furthermore will the `--aot` option have any impact? If you don't know, then do you have an suggestions on how I can test this?

Comment: ES6 module imports aren't duplicated by design. There is a scenario when different NPM packages have different dependency version restrictions or accidental duplicated dependencies (can be fixed with `npm dedupe`), this can result in having multiple package copies per bundle. But it is not the case if component A and B belong to the same package. Any way, Webpack bundle contents can be explored https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/690

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely no. The `ng build --prod` uses [Webpack module bundling](https://webpack.github.io/) system in the background to bundle the files. Webpack is intelligent enough to not duplicate the imports.

Using the `--aot` option is great. It uses Angular AOT Compilation to bundle the files. i.e Ahead Of Time Compilation, it simply means the Compilation of the angular files before it is been served to the client So this elimates the compilation phase which causes long loading times. Here is a better article to explain [Angular AOT](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html)